# mod_rewrite help - subdirectory turned into subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I  had `http://example.com/intranet/` which I  had to turn into `http://intranet.example.com`
Unfortunately, everything was written with the absolute path so its like `<a href="/intranet/timeclock">time clock</a>`

So you see my dilemma. everything wants to go to like /intranet/timeclock

I tried some rewrite rules like

```
    RewriteRule ^/intranet / [R,L]
    RewriteRule ^/intranet/(*.) /$1 [R,L]
```

And others. No luck. I have looked at the other posts on server fault and tried some of them with no luck either. Andy advice?

Comment: Can you, please, **clearly** describe what you want to rewrite: from => to. Do you want to rewrite `http://intranet.example.com/` into `http://example.com/intranet/`  ... or?

Comment: I would like "http://intranet.example.com/intranet/timeclock" to rewrite to "http://intranet.example.com/timeclock"

Comment: MrTuttle already gave an answer (301 Permanent Redirect). If you place his rule into Apache config file (inside `<VirtualHost>`, for example) it should work fine. If you are going to place it into .htaccess file, then you should remove leading slash `/`. The same goes for your own rules -- in .htaccess there is no leading slash when pattern is applied to URL in RewriteRule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteRule ^/intranet/(.*)$ http://intranet.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: thats seems like it would work but it does nothing. Am i doing something wrong with the .htaccess file i wonder?

Comment: Thats it! only its RewriteRule ^intranet/(.*)$ http://intranet.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]